# What is the cause of my website's extra white space width once below 614px wide

Tags: html, css, media-queries, width, whitespace

Once my site reaches 614px and less in width, white space appears to the right. I can't find any element that is causing this extra width. This is causing me particular issues for the mobile version of my website.

Here's the site:
https://frankli-n.github.io/portfolio/memsmosaics/filter/filterable-gallery/dist/m_index.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.M1-shape` has set `width: 600px` for resolution `< 800px`.

Set `max-width: 600px; width: 100%` to fix it.